# How to slow down rotation?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

So I wrote some code to make an object rotate if I swiped left or right

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotater : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        // GET TOUCH 0
        Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);

        // APPLY ROTATION
        if (touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            player.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, touch0.deltaPosition.x);
        }

    }
}
}
```

and the problem is when I swipe fast the rotation will be uncontrollable. So I want the input to be less sensitive.

my goal is for the rotation to be like [rolly vortex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnW8JIST7Jw)

my setup:

- I made an empty object and put it in the center
- made the empty object a parent of my player
- and finally, I put my code in the empty object

this setup made the player rotate in sort of an orbit which like I told you is similar to rolly vortex.

Comment: Please do not make people leave the site to get context into your project. Please provide a minimal viable example to explain your issue.

Comment: Do you want to have the rotation gradually slow down _after the swipe_ or do you just want the input to be less sensitive _during the swipe_?

Comment: @Foggzie just less sensitive

Comment: Suggest you use absolute rotations instead of increments because errors may accumulate.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to be able to scale the sensitivity. This means making it so that for every unit of change in touch position, you will get some multiple of a unit of change in the rotation. For this, make a configurable (public) member variable, `public float touchSensitivityScale`, and multiply the rotation by that value. Example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotater : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;
public float touchSensitivityScale;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        // GET TOUCH 0
        Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);

        // APPLY ROTATION
        if (touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            player.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, touch0.deltaPosition.x * touchSensitivityScale);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Now you can edit the touch sensitivity in the inspector. With `touchSensitivityScale` set to 1, the behavior will be identical to what it is currently. If you make the number 0.5, the rotation will be half as sensitive.

If this doesn't fully solve the problem and you also want some smoothing or acceleration, that might warrant an edit to the question.

I hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your help but unfortunately, this didn't work. yes, it slowed down the rotation but when I swipe fast it will rotate uncontrollably. here is a vid of what is happening https://youtu.be/eL0JK5x6Tz0

Comment: Thanks for the vid, that helps a good bit. It might just be that the sensitivity is dramatically too high? You could try a value like 0.05 and see if that's closer (or over-compensates).Otherwise we could try doing a kind of reverse acceleration, adding a log function to make it so that the rotation rate approaches some limit as your finger moves faster.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rotating by touch0.deltaPosition.x you could always have some sort of negative exponential function. In this case it’d probably be something along the lines of e^(-x-a) where x is your touch0.deltaPosition.x, and a would be a variable you’d have to determine based on how fast you want the initial speed of rotation. If you’re not familiar with exponential functions try using a graphing software like Desmos to plot y=e^(-x-a) and vary the value of a. Once you’ve visualised that it should be pretty self explanatory.